# The Left Headphone channel distrorted (bit crush and drop outs) at maximum volume

Tags: windows, audio, realtek-hd-audio

The left channel at max volume. If I lower it under 50 it works fine.

I can't use my 2.0 loudspeaker because of this. Does anybody know how I can possibly fix this?

New HP Laptop 15s, Windows 10, applied all updates

I tried all the typical solutions.
Uninstalled Realtek drivers, disabled enhancements, run troubleshooter, changed sample rates, etc

What can I do more? I don't get which drivers I should download. I have AMD chipset.

The same doesn't happen if I use an external sound card or just built-in speakers.

[image]

Comment: Are we to assume the same doesn't happen when connected to other devices? If so you should have explicitly said it in the question.

Comment: As the laptop is new, have you contacted HP support? Does your loudspeaker get the same amount of volume from other sources? Does it also have similar sound errors when it's high volume? You state that the laptop using other speakers works fine, but does the speaker work OK on other devices?

Comment: No, I didn't contact HP's support, my loudspeakers are fine.